# IAP / "Instrument Approach Procedure (IAP) Charts" What does "Procedure NA" Mean?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

The image below is of an FAA "Instrument Approach **Procedure**"

The entire thing is the "**Procedure**"

It contains a "Procedure **Turn**", which when not required typically states: "**NoPT**"

Now, in some places it states "**Procedure NA**" (red arrow near top) which seems to implicates the entire **Procedure** NOT the **Procedure Turn**.  However, the red arrow indication at top also seems to implicates the Procedure Turn because we're basically straight in from that location, so it wouldn't be needed, But again, NoPT would make more sense.  And why would the entire procedure be NA?

If we look at the two "Procedure NA" notes on the plan, then the entire "Procedure" would be NA from most approach directions.

So, Which is it?
Does "Procedure NA" mean The entire Instrument Approach Procedure?  or just the Procedure Turn?  If just the Procedure Turn, why does it use different vocabulary? Why not just say NoPT ?
Is there some other significance?

I looked in the chart user guide and can't find "Procedure NA" in it

Thanks

[image: KCON RNAV (GPS) RWY 17]

Answer (score 1):

Although the wording on the chart is very confusing, it appears to indicate that you can not make a course reversal at the VORs themselves. Probably due to the congestion of the airspace and associated airways. This is only the case when using the VORs for navigation to the IAFs since neither of the VORs is an IAF. However, the IAP is an RNAV IAP. So, you can disregard the VORs and use GPS only to navigate to the IAFs as long as you stay above he 4200 foot Minimum Sector Altitude and cross the IAFs at or above 4400 feet. Beware of the higher terrain with MAximum Elevation Figures of 5600 and 6600 feet NNE of the IAP.

In other words, it means that the entire procedure is invalid if you are using VORs to navigate to the area in some circumstances. If you are coming from the North and West, you are required to use LEB. If you are coming from the South and East, you are required to use CON. If you are using GPS only, you are required to navigate to the IAFs directly (not necessarily Direct-to) using GPS and not VORs.

Comment: So you agree that it means "Procedure Turn", NOT "Procedure" ?

Comment: No, it means that the entire procedure is invalid if you are using VORs to navigate to the area in some circumstances. If you are coming from the North and West, you are required to use LEB. If you are coming from the South and East, you are required to use CON. If you are using GPS only, you are required to navigate to the IAFs directly (not necessarily Direct-to) using GPS and not VORs.

Comment: Not sure why you think the wording is confusing. I think it is quite clear, although my Jeppesen charts use a longer version: "Procedure **not authorized** for arrivals on LEB VOR airway radials R-117 clockwise R-199."

Comment: @Bianfable - Because, to someone not used to the area, stuck in the soup, and diverted to this IAP by ATC (not their original planned alternate), this may take a second or two of precious brain power to fully grasp. They may not be looking at their sectional or low enroute to know that the notes apply to the inbound airways. I had to pull up a sectional to see that. But, I am on the ground, relaxing with a cup of coffee. The longer note is one of the reasons I prefer Jepp, too.

Comment: What do you mean "If you are coming from the North and West, you are required to use LEB"  How do you determine that?  I could be coming from LEB via radar vectors right?  Then I'm not required to use LEB?  If so, then I'm still coming from that direction, (I'm in that range of radials) but now the procedure is NOT NA ?  Thanks

Comment: If you are coming from the North and West using VORNav, you would pass LEB to get to CON. In which case, that direction is unusable for CON for this IAP. You would have to VORNav to LEB if you are coming from that direction. If you are being Radar Vectored, you are not using VORNav to get to the IAP. The directions ACT gives you will then make the notes irrelevant. ACT will Radar Vector you to the IAP beginning at least at one of the IAFs.

Comment: Try drawing a magnetic deviation corrected compass rose with Magnetic North for each VOR. The unusable portion of LEB for the purposes of this IAP would be the arc from 117° to 199° going ClockWise. The unusable portion of CON for the purposes of this IAP would be the arc from 330° to 088° going ClockWise. You can not use this IAP if and only if you are using VORNav as navigation to the VORs on these radials.